# Cronjob change email subject and sender name

Tags: debian, email, cron

I have a cronjob setup using crontab that looks like this...

```
MAILTO=myemail@example.com
00 02 * * * /home/myaccount/myscript.sh
```

This works great and at 2AM it runs the script and emails me the output to myemail@example.com

The only issue is that the email subject and the name of the sender aren't very useful.

Is there a way to change them in the same way i can set the recipient email address?

Can I suppress the automatic email and pipe the output to mail myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron doesn't allow for a lot of configuration, but you can do this, assuming you have the `mailutils` package installed:

```
00 02 * * * /home/myaccount/myscript.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "My subject" $MAILTO
```